# Changing order of csv-file entries with regex replacement in Notepad++

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

I am trying to change the order of the entries of an *.csv-file with Notepad++ built-in find/replace function. This is how the file looks like now:

```
ABC;DEF;Here comes some long text with ,.- in it;true;false;
QWE;RTY;Here comes some long text with ,.- in it;true;false;
```

And this is how it should look like after find/replace:

```
DEF;Here comes some long text with ,.- in it;ABC;true;false;;
RTY;Here comes some long text with ,.- in it;QWE;true;false;;
```

So column #1 should be at the position of #3, column number #2 and #3 should shift one to the left.

What I tried so far:

I tried to get the first three columns with an regular expression in the find field, put some brackets around them and reorder them with the $ sign in the replace field. **But my regex matches for nearly the whole line, not only the first three columns- what am I doing wrong?** Here is my regex:

```
([A-Z]{3})\;([A-Z]{3})\;(.*[^\;])\;
```

The first two columns and the following `;` are select properly, the problem must be in the third round bracket. But I have no clue what the problem is. The third expression should match to everything except `;` and is ended by an `;`.

The content of the replacement field should be `$2;$3;$1;`, I guess that's right.

Comment: You don't need to escape the semi colons. Your expression works if you don't escape them. Also you should use start of string anchor to be safe if you have more columns. `^([A-Z]{3});([A-Z]{3});([^;]*);`

Comment: You'd better use Excel© or LibreOffice

Comment: You'd be *way* better off to just use a scripting language (Perl, Python, Ruby, etc, etc) that has a csv parser and do the necessary manipulations there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you're escaping the semi-colons unnecessarily. Use this expression `^(?s)([A-Z]{3};)([A-Z]{3};)([^\n\r;]*;)` and replace it with this expression `$2$3$1`

Have included line delimiters `\r` or `\n` too in case of a line with fewer columns. Also you should use start of string anchor `^` to be safe if you have more columns.